# Stateful react-native functional component don't re-render when redux connected state change

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've started using hooks recently with react-native, so i have this connected component with a button that changes depending on a redux state. The button changes when redux state is updated inside the component, but not if it is from outside.

here is my button:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.goPremiumContainer}
   onPress={() => pay()}>
   {props.premiumLoading ? (
     <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />) 
     : 
    (<Text style={styles.goPremium}>
        {i18n.t('premium:go_premium')}
     </Text>)}
 </TouchableOpacity>

//
//
//

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    premiumLoading: state.premiumLoading,
  };
};

export default withNamespaces([], {wait: true})(
  connect(mapStateToProps)(Premium),
);
```

also the reducer:

```js
const initialState = false;

function updateButtonLoading(state = initialState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADING':
      nextState = true;
      return nextState || state;
    case 'NOT_LOADING':
      nextState = false;
      return nextState || state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default updateButtonLoading;
```

To update the button i call this action function:

```js
async updatePremiumButton(actionType) {
  console.log('actionType',actionType)
  const action = {type: actionType};
  const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => true);
  await store.dispatch(action);
  await unsubscribe();
      },
```

**THANKS!**

Comment: Are you sure it's updating? The logic in the `NOT_LOADING` case doesn't seem right. `nextState` is set to false which means doing `nextState || state` will always return `state`. So it appears that once `updateButtonLoading` gets set to `true` it can't be changed to `false`.

Comment: thats exactly my issue, the spinner starts and never stops, i will modify the code for 'NOT_LOADING' and see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, it working now when i return only `nextState`, you can add you answer so i can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the logic inside your reducer.

```js
switch (action.type) {
  case 'LOADING':
    nextState = true;
    return nextState || state;
  case 'NOT_LOADING':
    nextState = false;
    return nextState || state;
  default:
    return state;
}
```

It appears that what you really want to do is return the value you assign `nextState`, but the logic reads differently.

Currently the logic reads: If `nextState` is truthy use it, else return previous state.

In the `NOT_LOADING` case, you are intending to return the value `false`, but the logic reads: If `false` is true, return `false`, else return `true`. So you can see why this would never work.

Instead, simplify the cases and just return what you want the state to be. The `||` conditions don't seem to be necessary.

```js
function updateButtonLoading(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADING':
      return true;
    case 'NOT_LOADING':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```